# Firefox is getting failed on startup very first time with error connection refused

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

### System

- GeckoDriver Version: 0.24.0
- Platform:  Window 10
- Firefox: 65.0
- Selenium: 3.141.59

### Testcase

When I am running `Firefox` driver, very first time it's getting failed after that it's working fine on every run.

This is happening by following way :

- If I'm using selenium standalone server, on every restart of selenium server.
- On every restart of my machine
- If I'm using selenium standalone server and trying to run multiple thread with multiple browser simultaneously, All browsers work well except Firefox, This can be fail on any run.

### Stacktrace

> ```
> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused
>     Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
>     System info: host: 'SAURABH-PC', ip: '192.168.3.8', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version:
> '1.8.0_161'
>     Driver info: driver.version: unknown
>     remote stacktrace: 
>     Command duration or timeout: 66.09 seconds
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:54)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>       at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>       at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:252)
> ```

### Code

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:49153/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

### Command to run `Selenium-standalone.jar`

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=<path-to-geckodriver>\geckodriver.exe -jar <path-to-selenium-server-standalone.jar>\selenium-server-standalone.jar -port 49153
```

### Trace level logs

```
Feb 06, 2019 6:29:24 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities firefox
INFO: Using `new FirefoxOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.firefox()`
Feb 06, 2019 6:29:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"connection refused","stacktrace":""}}
1549457898669   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\Saurabh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.2UOp20Lx725Q"
1549457899002   geckodriver::marionette DEBUG   Waiting 60s to connect to browser on 127.0.0.1:51325
1549457915749   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: resource://pdf.js/
1549457915749   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: about:reader*
1549457916114   Marionette  TRACE   Received observer notification profile-after-change
1549457917888   Marionette  TRACE   Received observer notification toplevel-window-ready
1549457918713   Marionette  TRACE   Received observer notification command-line-startup
1549457918714   Marionette  TRACE   Received observer notification nsPref:changed
1549457918714   Marionette  DEBUG   Init aborted (running=false, enabled=true, finalUIStartup=false)
1549457925550   Marionette  TRACE   Received observer notification toplevel-window-ready
1549457948093   Marionette  TRACE   Received observer notification sessionstore-windows-restored
1549457948093   Marionette  TRACE   Waiting until startup recorder finished recording startup scripts...
1549457959572   mozrunner::runner   DEBUG   Killing process 11516
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
1549457960997   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 500 Internal Server Error {"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"connection refused","stacktrace":""}}
1549457965775   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\Saurabh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.0d9kqn5LP57h"
1549457965997   geckodriver::marionette DEBUG   Waiting 60s to connect to browser on 127.0.0.1:51620
1549457995244   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: resource://pdf.js/
1549457995245   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: about:reader*
1549457995902   Marionette  TRACE   Received observer notification profile-after-change
1549457998402   Marionette  TRACE   Received observer notification toplevel-window-ready
1549457998814   Marionette  TRACE   Received observer notification command-line-startup
1549457998814   Marionette  TRACE   Received observer notification nsPref:changed
1549457998814   Marionette  DEBUG   Init aborted (running=false, enabled=true, finalUIStartup=false)
```

Comment: Please add the code how you instantiate the driver; the exception is a timeout after 66s, and the driver version in it is unknown - so the selenium client cannot start the server (geckodriver) for some reason or another, it may be something in the connection string. Another obvious question - you have checked any firewall rules that may be blocking the Java process from connections, right?

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Please avoid using the `<blockquote>` markup for the errors as they gets word-wrapped and debugging the error becomes difficult.

Comment: @TodorMinakov updated with code, but there is no problem with code I think because it is running with same code all the time, the problem is only occurs when I run it very first time. and also problem arise at any run If I run multiple thread with multiple driver instances with different browser or same with selenium server.

Comment: @TodorMinakov There is no firewall issue, I have checked..

Comment: @TodorMinakov this is my question why stacktrace showing unknown version while I have provided.

Comment: So ok, it's a remote connection, the client doesn't request the server to be started, it's running on its own. Does this error depend on the time when the selenium server is started - what I mean is, you may be attempting a connection before the server is fully up?

Comment: @TodorMinakov No, server is already started..:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur How are you trying to use `selenium-server-standalone.jar`? As a _Selenium Server_ or _Selenium Grid_ configuration?

Comment: @SaurabhGaur what's the output of the status check - **before** the very first code attempt to start a Firefox session, e.g. when it will time out? The url is `http://localhost:49153/wd/hub/status`, the request should be a GET. Also, if after this req you can successfully connect for the initial code connection, you can use this as a workaround

Comment: @DebanjanB As a selenium server

Comment: @TodorMinakov Actually I'm running server before initializing driver, the server is always is in running state. If I'm trying to access `http://localhost:49153/wd/hub/status` it gives me response as `{
  "status": 0,
  "value": {
    "ready": true,
    "message": "Server is running",
    "build": {
      "revision": "e82be7d358",
      "time": "2018-11-14T08:25:53",
      "version": "3.141.59"
    },
    "os": {
      "arch": "amd64",
      "name": "Windows 10",
      "version": "10.0"
    },
    "java": {
      "version": "1.8.0_161"
    }
  }
}`...

Comment: > "I'm running server before initializing driver" - yep, that part is understood, we're trying to debug why the very first connection times out, while all follow-up succeeds. The question is - after a successful response on that `wd/hub/status`, does the first connection time out again, or now it succeeds?

Comment: @TodorMinakov Nothing succeed, Same problem..:)

Comment: Well your question _obviously_ caught my interest, but these were all the tricks I have for it :) Looking at possible to causes, I've seen similar bugs being submitted to the project itself - one for chromedriver 4 years ago, and one for firfox two years back. I'd kindly suggest you take that route - if you don't get a real answer here soon. At the end, it may very well be a problem others may see and for the selenium maintainers to fix.

Comment: @TodorMinakov Thank you so much for your help, I think this `geckodriver` problem not `selenium`, as you have suggested, I've already logged an issue [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1495)..

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused 
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53' System info: host: 'SAURABH-PC', ip: '192.168.3.8', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161' Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

...implies that the **GeckoDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowsing Session** i.e. **Firefox Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_161** which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u161* , *Selenium Client v3.141.59* , *GeckoDriver v0.24.0* and the *Firefox Browser v65.0*

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u191**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response, I think you are going with right direction but if it is JDK issue, why is it not failing every time then?

Comment: jdk version has nothing to do with it